# How do i fix this minor indent issue with vim?

Tags: vim, macvim

If I have `:setf html` everything works as expected in the below example (the indentation matches up).

say however, i have the following code (note the indent before the code), except i have it on `:setf php`.

the | is the cursor

```
       <div class="sig">|</div>
```

If I hit enter, it does this

```
       <div class="sig">
|</div>
```

Because 99% of the time im editing php there is html in the template file, i find it kind of annoying to switch.

I feel like there must be a way for vim to read  markers and perhaps have multiple filetypes in one document (just like if `setf=html` it could maybe read the style tags or an inline style tag and 'know' that that little snippet in the "" is a css filetype

Comment: My vim (7.3.429 in Debian) behaves well. Could you post your `.vimrc` file? Maybe that will help us a bit.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/2657638

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this help?

```
:setfiletype html.php
```